# Bitcoin unconfirmed long Time no confirmations

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

Been forever my bitcoin hasn’t been confirmed can someone help me

3JHLiBT2Tu6uFotFRY1mF1bAnRdRS8XTqt

Comment: Both transactions involving that address are confirmed, as of a couple hours ago. https://blockchain.info/address/3JHLiBT2Tu6uFotFRY1mF1bAnRdRS8XTqt

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations! Your transaction at the time of writing has 65 confirmations!

[blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx/9cdf316785ee0b42bdd1d6843bfdd7519a164ca90ab67afc283f013ea01a2c95)